show itinerary instructions (route) leaflet osmr
I'm using leaflet with osrm to create a map, at the begining it showed the instructions butand I removed it by adding .leaflet-routing-container {display: none;}, but now I got asked to show the instructions again, I tried to remove that line or set it to .leaflet-routing-container {display: block;} but it didn't worked. What can I do to show the instuctions again? I'm using Angular btw
Idk if that's have something to do with the component or anything, 'cause i don't know nothing about leaflet or osrm. So if anyone need my component (it's kinda long) please let me know
Before
After
I tried removing or changing .leaflet-routing-container {display: none;}, I tried using ChatGPT too and nothing seems to works, I just want to show the instructions like in the first image
Or show something like this

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
